# Is there a way to hook into the save event in Visual Studio 2012 Express Editions?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a collection of js, html, css files. I have an app that builds all of these files into a single page. When working on these js, html, and css files in Visual Studio I would like to have the page built every time they are saved. This way when I save any of the pages I can just refresh the browser and they will show up.

So is there a way to hook into when the save and save as events are fired within Visual Studio?

Comment: having a hook into the vs save event saves me the step of having to save in vs and THEN click build in my app.

Comment: I don't think VS Express has any extensibility points that would let that work. Developing an Add On is easy enough, but they require Pro or better.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documenteventsclass.documentsaved.aspx  You can't use it in Express.